# Pycharm:Numpy install package failed

Tags: pycharm

[pycharm numpy installation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jymyn.jpg**)

its asking to install Microsoft visual C++ but after installing also not working

Comment: Have you restarted PyCharm after installing Build Tools for Visual Studio?

Comment: i have installed visual studio c++ but after i dont know what to do

Comment: See this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/60446737/2235698