# Unable to install NumPy in PyCharm version 9.3.3. Python version 3.8.2

Tags: python, numpy, pip, pycharm

Error while installing NumPy in PyCharm.

[image: pip install error]

Tried installing Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 . Still not working. NumPy is getting installed by command `pip3 install numpy` in the cmd terminal but when trying to install it in project interpreter in PyCharm this error pops up. I have checked other forums with similar error but am not able to find a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved**

When installing visual studio [link]
(https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/)

Offline Installer:
[https://aka.ms/vs/16/release/vs_buildtools.exe]

Tick the checkbox of C++ build tools option in the installer. It will be 
around 2 Gb.

Once installed it will tell you to restart your system. After restarting

Go to Pycharm --> File --> Settings --> Project --> Project interpreter --> click the + symbol at the top right side , serach for numpy and click install package.

Answer (score 0):

Try upgrading your version of pip using this command --> `python -m pip install --upgrade pip`

Then use the following command to install the numpy --> `pip install numpy`

Answer (score 0):

Install visual studio c++ -> build tools C++

restart the machine and then go to pycharm->settings->project->project interpreter-> click on + symbol on the right top-> search for numpy -> click install package at the left bottom

now you should be good